# ruby on rails multiple step form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-step, wicked-gem

I have been doing some research into using multistep forms for my ruby on rails project, and have come across the wicked gem which seems to tick all the boxes. Upon further investigation, I see it is only good for showing/updating. does anyone know if its possible to use this gem for creating as I want to use the link for my signup process which will show a different set of fields depending on if the user selects they are a customer or a supplier?

Comment: Yes it possible. In your first view you use to create a user on `RegistrationsController` and after create you redirect to next step. You need to override a `registrations_controller.rb`

Comment: yeah i dont really want to create the user first, i wanted the end user to select customer or supplier then display the fields, but it looks like i might not be able to do this

Comment: Ok. But what's the model you need update when user select bettwen customer ou supplier ? User, correct? if yes need override the action `update` on `registrations_controller.rb` and when the user save you `redirect_to` wicked or other view. `redirect_ to customer_user_path` or `supplier_user_path` or using wicked `wizard_path(:supplier)`

Comment: yes its the user, that will be updated as can belong to many suppliers

Comment: You know, sometimes, using plain HTML and JS makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this gem

https://github.com/schneems/wicked

It seems to bring some wizard functionality to your rails app.